# open image recently created with Intent.ACTION_VIEW in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-file, actionview

I have a task like this, if the user wants to download the image, he will click on the blue button, the image will be downloaded,and the snack bar will be shown, if the user clicks on the action of the snack bar the image will be open [image]

the problem is i can't see the image when the user click on the action of snack bar, just a black screen will be shown, the image is created and i can see it with my file explorer and my gallery

here is my code used to download the image

```
    val picturesDirectory: File =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

            try {
                var localFile = File(picturesDirectory, "picture.jpg")
                val out = FileOutputStream(localFile)
               
                  val bitmapDrawable = imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable
                    bitmapDrawable.bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
                    out.flush()
                    out.close()
                }
                context.sendBroadcast(
                    Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
                    )
                )

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getPhotoFile: ${e.message}")
            }
```

And the part used to show the image

```
 val picturesDirectory: File =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
              
               val image = File(picturesDirectory,"picture.jpg")
                  val intent = Intent()
                  intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(image), "image/*")
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                  startActivity(intent)
```

As i said, the image is created, and the path is the same but the viewer can't display it,
I tried to show another image with the same intent viewer code, it shows it normally, so the problem is it can't show the image recently created.
Also i tried with FileProvider, it's not a problem of security or restriction, because i test the application with SDK 21
Any solution ?.
Update: when i rename the image with file explorer, it will be shown normally

Comment: You should use `FileProvider.getUriForFile` I guess

Comment: i tried it, it's not a problem of restriction, because i tried withoud FileProvider with another file(not recently create) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i must add

```
         val contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                mediaScanIntent.data = contentUri
                requireActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
```

after creating the file